# Dynamically Affixed Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on a web page, and I looked up how to make a dynamically affixed navigation bar. In other words a navbar that is fixed to the bottom of a header image but then fixes itself to the top when the user scrolls down past the header. Most of the stuff I saw was confusing, but I got a general idea of what needed to be done. I made a quick 4 line JQuery code to set the data-offset-top value to the outerHeight of the div containing the header. It worked and I was content with what I'd done. The navbar would stick to the bottom of the header and switch over even when the screen size was scaled up or down. Then I started to add content... now it's setting the data-offset-top to 23, and being new to JQuery, I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var affixHeight = $(".header").outerHeight(true);
 $("#affixNav").attr("data-offset-top", affixHeight);
});
```

```css
/*Primary Background*/
body{
  background-image: url("AtABackgroundImage.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.horizon{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-top: 2px outset #8c8c8c;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
/*div{
  border: 5px solid red;
}*/
/*Navbar/Header*/
.navElement{
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-inverse{
  background-image: url("AtABackgroundImage.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-width: 0;
}
.hovering:hover{
  background-color: #1f1f14;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.button-images{
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge #333333;
}
.headerimg{
  margin-top: -125px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: none;
}
.affix {
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

/*Index Content*/
.row{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.content-area{

}
.logoArea{
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.logoImg{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.indexTextImg{
  text-align: left;
  height: 55px;
  width: 225px;
}
.index-text{
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="atamain.css">
        <link rel="icon" 
            type="image/ico" 
            href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="atamain.js"></script>
  <title>Ashes to Ashes</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header container-fluid">
   <img class="headerimg" src="header\AtAWallpaper.jpg">
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar-inverse navbar" data-spy="affix" id="affixNav">
    <div class="container-fluid nav-containment">
      <div class="navbar-header active-page">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="hovering navElement"><a href="index.html"><img class="button-images" src="NavButtonAssets\HOME2.png"></a></li>
     <li class="hovering navElement"><a href="news.html"><img class="button-images" src="NavButtonAssets\NEWS2.png"></a></li>
       <li class="dropdown hovering navElement">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="button-images" src="NavButtonAssets\ABOUT2.png"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="game.html">The Game</a></li> 
         <li><a href="server.html">The Server</a></li> 
         <li><a href="factions.html">Factions</a></li> 
     </ul> 
        <li class="hovering navElement"><a href="media.html"><img class="button-images" src="NavButtonAssets\MEDIA2.png"></a></li> 
        <li class="hovering navElement"><a href="application.html"><img class="button-images" src="NavButtonAssets\APPLY2.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content-area">
   <div class=" row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 logoArea"><img class="logoImg" src="NavBarLogo\AshesWebNavBarLogo.png" alt="AtA Logo"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 welcomeTextArea">
     <img class="indexTextImg" src="NavButtonAssets\WELCOME.png">
     <hr class="horizon">
     <p class="index-text">Placeholder text is here to test if the page works... it will eventually be changed to something actually useful and meaningful. For now... it's just here.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is very unclear what your issue is. From your snippet, it looks like to me it is "affixing to the top when the user scrolls down past the header" like you've mentioned. You are going to need to elaborate more before anyone can provide much help.

Comment: Ok... so you see the JavaScript/JQuery. It's meant to take the outerHeight of the first div in my html (class="header"). It then takes that value and sets the value of the NavBar's data-offset-top. This was working fine. I would load the page, see the header with the navbar affixed to the bottom of it, scroll down and upon hitting the top of the page the navbar would fix to the top. THEN I added content underneath... now the JQuery not getting the height or anything. It's simply setting the data-offset-top to 23.

Comment: The system changed since I last posted so 1) I didn't know how to post just a snippet and 2) I didn't really know what was exactly important because I don't know if the problem is in the css, the JQuery, or the HTML.